# how to build spring boot initializ from source on Mac OS with M-1

Tags: spring-boot, apple-m1

source code was download from https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io.git
when ran "./mvnw clean install", I got error below:
[image]

my os is Mac OS Monterey 12.4 with Apple M1 Pro, I notice that https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.19.3/node-v14.19.3-darwin-arm64.tar.gz does not exist, but don't know how get arount with it.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node 16 supports Apple Silicon so you may be able to get this to work by locally upgrading the version of Node that start.spring.io uses in its build. If the changes for that prove to be too involved, please open an issue against the project (I am one of the maintainers) to see if Node can be upgraded.

Comment: issue open https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io/issues/973